# Mulesoft : HTML to JSON conversion?

Tags: html, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

Is it possible to convert an html input to JSON using mulesoft?

For my case specifically, I am trying to convert an HTML table to JSON arrays.

Input:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>id</td><td>value1</td><td>value2</td></tr>
<tr><td>0 </td><td>0     </td><td>0     </td></tr>
<tr><td>0 </td><td>1.5   </td><td>2.15  </td></tr>
</table>
```

Output:

```
"JsonOutput" :[
  {id:"0",value1:"0",value2:"0"},
  {id:"1",value1:"1.5",value2:"2.15"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is fetch the top `tr` element from the `table` and use it to determine the headers. Then you can create the JSON dynamically using that headers array.

```js
%dw 2.0
var tableAsArray = payload.table.*tr
var tableHeaderRow = tableAsArray[0].*td
var tableValuesRow = tableAsArray[1 to -1]
output application/json  
---
{
  "JsonOutput": tableValuesRow map ((tr) -> {
    (tr.*td map ((td, index) -> {
      (tableHeaderRow[index]): td
    }))
  })
}
```